# Set custom error page per master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have a front-page.Master and backoffice.Master.

I don't want the same error-message to be shown (and the redirect should be different)

How can I achieve this?

- Redirect an error in /backoffice/ default to **~/backoffice/error.aspx** instead of **~/error.aspx**

This is my current web.config-snippet:

```
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
 <error statusCode="404" redirect="NotFound.aspx" />
 </customErrors>
```

Comment: You could not add conditional error page based on Master page in web.config. However you could grab the error in `Page_Error` event of your master page and redirect it.

Comment: Yeah in web config you can only set the default error page, Indeed you can catch the exception/error and then redirect to your respective pages

Answer (score 1):

You can have another web.config file under ~/BackOffice/ (~/BackOffice/Web.config) with the above snippet directing to another error page.